# Tag "busca" precisa de mais sinónimos

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

Ao preencher as informações sobre a [busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/busca), reparei que a mesma tem um único sinónimo: [search](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/search)

Então e os termos comuns aqui em Portugal e/ou outros no Brasil?

Em Portugal, "busca" é extremamente raro ver-se aplicado neste ambiente. Termos comuns são:

- pesquisa
- localizar
- procurar

Deveremos criar sinónimos para [busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/busca) de forma a contemplar estes e outros termos?

Comment: Acho que era boa ideia criar.

Comment: Adicionei as sugestões das tags no sistema. Agora os usuários com reputação precisam votar nelas para confirmá-las ou rejeitá-las.

Comment: Apesar de que não sei exatamente como fica a questão de não existir nenhuma pergunta com essas tags. Vale a pena? E ainda preciso ver como o sistema vai tratar isso, pois tinha alguma coisa sobre o sistema apagar tags vazia. O @bfavaretto é o *expert* nesses detalhes.